# Query results of another query

Tags: sql, group-by

Here is my first query that works fine.

```
SELECT count(event_log_id) as icount, cast(youth_name as varchar(max)) as yname
FROM CIRComplete
WHERE  actual_date between '2012-01-01' and '2012-04-30'
  AND is_deleted = '0' AND Closed = '1' 
GROUP BY cast(youth_name as varchar(max))
```

This will give me two columns, icount and yname

I want to perform a second query that will give me yname and icount where icount > 1

I have been at this for hours now and have finally decided to ask for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why a second query? This should do:

```
SELECT
   count(event_log_id) as icount ,
   cast(youth_name as varchar(max)) as yname 
   FROM CIRComplete 
   WHERE (actual_date between '2012-01-01' and '2012-04-30') and 
         is_deleted = '0' and Closed = '1' 
   GROUP BY cast(youth_name as varchar(max))
   HAVING count(event_log_id) > 1
```

Comment: Thank you all for the quick response.  I totally forgot about the Having clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  cast(youth_name as varchar(max)) as yname,
        count(event_log_id) as icount
FROM    CIRComplete
WHERE   (actual_date between '2012-01-01' AND '2012-04-30') AND 
        is_deleted = '0' AND 
        Closed = '1' 
GROUP BY cast(youth_name as varchar(max))
HAVING  count(event_log_id) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  
   count(event_log_id) as icount
  ,cast(youth_name as varchar(max)) as yname
FROM
  CIRComplete
WHERE 
   (actual_date between '2012-01-01' and '2012-04-30') and is_deleted = '0' and Closed = '1' 
GROUP BY
   cast(youth_name as varchar(max))
having icount > 1
```

Comment: Is using an alias in the having clause really permissible?

Comment: Depends on the database, but this is non-standard and uncommon SQL.